# Video upload stops when I change to another tab

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, video, video-upload

I am making an api call for video upload from one of component .
As long as i stay in that tab upload works fine .
But when i switch to another tab, Since the component is unmounted, API call stops and i lose the upload.

How can i make the Upload(API call) to continue even if I keep navigating the tabs in my application.

I am trying to achieve this in vue js.

Comment: Hi! You will need a component that will still active no matter where users goes. If you use vue3 maybe this could help you. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/teleport.html

Comment: try keep-alive https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html or you can do upload request in store